# How can i get angular native element's real chidren?

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas

I would like to use a canvas element in angular. So my HTML file looks like this:

```
<canvas id="canvas" myCanvas></canvas>
```

I try to get it with .nativeElement. Like this:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[myCanvas]' })

export class DrawComponent implements OnInit {

  cx;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    console.log(el.nativeElement)
    this.cx = el.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
   }
```

With it i got a duoble HTML tag:

```
<app-draw _nghost-c1>
   <canvas _ngcontent-c1="" id="canvas" mycanvas=""></canvas>
</app-draw>
```

And it says to .getContext('2d') it is not a function.
If i try to put after the .nativeElement the .children selecter like this:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[myCanvas]' })

export class DrawComponent implements OnInit {

  cx;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    console.log(el.nativeElement.children)
    this.cx = el.nativeElement.children.getContext('2d');
   }
```

I got a list:

[]
canvas: canvas#canvas
length: 1
0: canvas#canvas
**proto**: HTMLCollection

And the same result to the .getContext function.
How can i use it properly?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `ViewChild`?

Comment: I've tried it already, but i can't reached it, it was undefined no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested it:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[myCanvas]' })
export class DrawComponent implements OnInit {
   ...
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
     this.cx = el.nativeElement.querySelector("canvas").getContext('2d');
  }
```

children is an Array so you must specify the index but better is to select the element because index can change

```
...querySelector("canvas").getContext('2d');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but now i have this error message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

Comment: i think its because we do this in constructor, I eddited my post. Try now please

Comment: In the ngOnInit function, it wroked with the .children[0] as well, thank you for your help :)